# Inmobi.com "ad request successful but no ad served"

Tags: android, inmobi

When I try to load an interstitial with inmobi.com and most of the times I get the error "**ad request successful but no ad served**". Why is this happening? Any solution for this? It works well with testing ads when set to "Test mode" in the website. Will this be because inmobi has not enough providers to display ads at that moment?

I asked Inmobi support page but they don't answer. I am starting to regret moving from admob to inmobi.

This is the code I use:

```
JSONObject consentObject = new JSONObject();
try {        
    consentObject.put(InMobiSdk.IM_GDPR_CONSENT_AVAILABLE, true); // Provide correct consent value to sdk which is obtained by User        
    consentObject.put("gdpr", "1"); // Provide 0 if GDPR is not applicable and 1 if applicable        
    //consentObject.put(InMobiSdk.IM_GDPR_CONSENT_IAB, “<<consent in IAB format>>”); // Provide user consent in IAB format
} catch (JSONException e) {        
}


InMobiSdk.init(this, "My InMobi Account ID here", consentObject); 
long MyPlacementID = 1234566789L;  //My Placement ID here as long
mInterstitialAd = new InMobiInterstitial(this, MyPlacementID,  new InterstitialAdEventListener() { 
@Override
public void onAdLoadSucceeded(InMobiInterstitial inMobiInterstitial) {
    super.onAdLoadSucceeded(inMobiInterstitial);
    if (inMobiInterstitial.isReady()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
}
@Override
public void onAdLoadFailed(InMobiInterstitial inMobiInterstitial, InMobiAdRequestStatus inMobiAdRequestStatus) {
    sError = inMobiAdRequestStatus.getMessage();
    Here I get error:  "ad request successful but no ad served"
}
```

Comment: any solution yet? I'm facing same problem.

Comment: See my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the support team and they answered that is shown if they don't have any ad to be displayed (maybe for my location or for my time). So, it is just that they run out of ads to be displayed. If I try it many many times then I may get one ad. So it is a server problem. Not enough clients to pay for ads. It is a pity.

Comment: But I'm using test ad requests. How come there's no any test ad from InMobi?

Comment: If you are using test mode from the dashboard then you should use the physical device and avoid emulators to get a test ad.

Comment: do you still use it? I also have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650344/inmobi-ads-doesnt-appear-ad-request-successful-but-no-ad-served-no-fill test ads works ok, but I've never seen a real ad

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.I tried different ways to get the test ads.But everything was in vein.Then i went through their documentation and found that we need to set up a layout for ad placement.There is an option to customize that.Click on save and then add your device id in the testing devices section, you will see test ads coming up.I found this one from an article where it said "If you set banner sizes different from those provided by default, the SDK will refuse to load data and will issue a corresponding message to the log:

[InMobi]: Failed to fetch ad for placement id: 201901231449, reason phrase available in onAdLoadFailed callback.

And the message “Ad request successful but no ad served” with the code “NO_FILL” appears in the listener's method. Hence our expert advice: always redefine the listener's methods which are responsible for errors. Acting such a way, you'll avoid many difficulties later."

https://agilie.com/en/blog/how-to-integrate-inmobi-sdk-to-start-monetizing-your-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Contradicting answer to @Ton's answer.

All the ad servers work in the following manner. Advertisers pay for ads with specific targetted audiences. So whenever you ask an ad network to provide an ad it actually checks if they have an ad for which targeting is matched with the current user (for ex. area, gender, age as and when available). If they don't have any ad which can be shown to the current user then they will fire NO_FILL.

Also, specific to InMobi, they don't provide many ads on emulators so try on a physical device to get ads.