# InMobi ad doesn't appear - Ad request successful but no ad served. NO_FILL

Tags: android, inmobi

I integrated InMobi SDK to my Andorid app, added one ad banner and one fullscreen ad.

I enabled test mode on InMobi site ad settings page for my ads and they were showing up ok (test ads).

[image]

But if I disable this option, then there are no any ads, listener in `override fun onAdLoadFailed(p0: InMobiBanner, p1: InMobiAdRequestStatus)` prints `Ad request successful but no ad served. NO_FILL`

[image]

It's already on Google Play, but still there are no any stats on their site about views, earnings, so nobody see any adds (app has ~70000 users)

Answer (score 0):

The InMobi SDK relies on other dependencies from Google - like play-services-ads-identifier.

Be sure to integrate the deps from this guide: https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/android-guidelines (Section: Add & Verify Dependencies).
It needs Google Play Services, Chrome Custom Tab (exchanged with Browser in AndroidX!), Picasso Library, Support Library, RecyclerView.

Comment: Yes, I have all of that, and it doesn't work. Support Library is also deprecated, it's appcompat right now, there is no such thing as support library (only legacy-support-library), here my deps for this SDK: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:9.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`

Comment: test ads also would not show up if I'd not add those deps

Comment: @user924 are you seeing any ad impressions? or all the ad requests are failing with NO_FILL?

Comment: @RajSuvariya no ads, I stopped using it, there are much more better platforms, you can try mopub, unity ads, chartboost, facebook network (if available in your country) - this really works, can earn money, but of course admob is the best choice, you can use mopub and add other platforms as mediation to mopub (the same as with admob)